# Parse Array Response From Server

Tags: android

How to Parse Array response using Gson in android. and how to pass model class in retrofit request.Please Give me Answer of this question i m facing this problem using array response.

```
private void getitemlist() {
        apiInterface.getVendorItems("_apiagent_/_data_agentPSS.php?k=825k9mksd35terijfh36374fhfgr7362hdfhf74&v=2&w=N_vendor_idEQUALTO"+getIntent().getStringExtra("userid")).enqueue(new Callback<GetItems>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetItems> call, Response<GetItems> response) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetItems> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

please check the link of this api response

[http://fssai.cmis.co.in/*apiagent*/_data_agentPSS.php?k=825k9mksd35terijfh36374fhfgr7362hdfhf74&v=3](http://fssai.cmis.co.in/_apiagent_/_data_agentPSS.php?k=825k9mksd35terijfh36374fhfgr7362hdfhf74&v=3)
Response setrt with  Json Array

Comment: What have you tried? You should edit your question and add some code of where your have aproblem so we can better understand how to help.

Comment: please remove the negative vote  i  update the queation with code okk

Comment: Charanveer, the downvote wasn't mine. Unfortunately people do that a lot without leaving comments, but don't worry about that.

Comment: possible reason of downvote is because you didn't spend enough time searching for the solution yourself.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i am sure you are looking for this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<HubLoginApus>>(){}.getType();
List<HubLoginApus> posts = gson.fromJson(response.body(), listType);
```